# Unable to upload videos to youtube using java API (oAuth2). Receiving 403 Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized

Tags: java, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have an application which uploads videos to YouTube. Since 24 feb my application have serious issues with upload functionality. I'm using official google java client for youtube (and oauth as well).

The problem that I'm receiving `403 Forbidden` using video upload API. 
The refresh token, auth bearer header are ok.

When I run my application first time it successfully uploads 1-2 videos and then a bit later it receives `403` from google on new requests which reuses the same connection authorization.

I even reproduced the problem in oauth playground.

How to reproduce?

1. Enter application oauth credentials in google oauth playground
2. Authorize `youtube.upload` API
3. Exchange auth token in order to get refresh token
4. From api test section execute POST to https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&prettyPrint=true&uploadType=resumable - It should create empty video stub before upload

First 1-3 times the POST creates video stubs with correct youtube video id, but later it responds with:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.common", 
        "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.", 
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's the full response:

[image]

Comment: Looks like latest youtube update introduced kind of capping limit which prevents upload more than 1 video within 15 minutes.

Comment: Earlier today I saw the API allow 30 video uploads in very quick succession, but then not allow any uploads for around 15 minutes between attempts.

Need to test more really to try and work out exactly what the rules are. It's annoying the error response isn't more helpful. I hope this is a bug rather than the start of a new feature..

Comment: Product Forums
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/9rOFZN_xYzk
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/tSPtIZcpn5I
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CHkD9CETtKk
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/KkH6VlmpfMU
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/PbbCySPyBO0

Stack overflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462748/unable-to-upload-videos-to-youtube-using-java-api-oauth2-receiving-403-access
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498808/youtube-data-api-intermittently-throw-access-forbidden

Comment: The above are the URLs to forum discussion on this topic.

Comment: I'm not alone then.... I e-mailed support and my query was sent on to the dev team. You'd think support would know if a cap had been introduced. It certainly looks like it has though.

Comment: Ok, here first responses from google side: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708

The limit of 50 (google tells 100) videos per day was introduced, so it's not a bug, it's a feature. They will rework response message to get clear indication that it's a limit.

Comment: I got half an answer from support but it mentions nothing of an intentional change: “Currently, our engineers are aware of the problem and is still working hard to resolve it.

At the moment, I'm unable to provide a specific timeline for a solution, however once our engineers have applied the fix, it will be automatically implemented in our systems.”