# youtube data api intermittently throw access forbidden

Tags: youtube-data-api

I need to upload considerable amount of videos on YouTube, so I have a c# application, upload one file each 5 minutes. The problems is, it intermittently throw "access forbidden". For example it worked for around 4 hours this morning, then it became moody again :D. Any same experience recently with YouTube API?

It's the error I receive sometimes, but not always, after successful authentication, when it tries to upload:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[youtube.common]
]
```

Comment: I've seen this for the last two days. I sent a support request but haven't heard anything back. I thought it would be odd if I were alone in this. It's been working without issue for months until two days ago.

Comment: I am seeing this too, as are people in the discussions linked below - it would seem YouTube have put in place some kind of anti-spam limitations, but no-one seems to know what they are

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/tSPtIZcpn5I
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/CHkD9CETtKk
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/9rOFZN_xYzk

Comment: Yo Joe, just by monitoring my app, seems since this morning (AU Time), it fixed to only allow one upload each 15 minutes. It's at least a progress, shows they are working on it :)

Comment: Hi Sep - you seem to be able to upload 50 videos, then get throttled to 1 every 15 minutes. I'm still to work out when this throttle gets reset.

Comment: Since Feb 28 our platform is having similar issues with uploading.  However, our analysis of the quota/rate-limits isn't yet clear.

Comment: Been having the same problem. The Google APIs console does show some quotas for the YouTube Data API, but from what I can see we shouldn't be close to hitting them.

Comment: I am also getting this after 50 uploads. My new strategy is to only upload 50 videos per day

Comment: Someone pointed this out to me today - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708

Comment: One of my users has said after uploading 50 videos, if you leave a 90 minute gap, you can upload another 50, then a 90 minute gap, then another 50 - and so on.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks for sharing your user's experience. I had tested a similar scenario few days ago with  2 hours gap but didn't work for me and after 2 hours it let me just fill that 2 hours gap. But maybe I had done something wrong :)