# Why am I getting an Access forbidden error when using the youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

When uploading videos to YouTube using the YouTube api v3, I get the following error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized. [403]
Errors [
    Message[Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[youtube.common]
]
```

The app will successfully upload a couple videos, then randomly throws this 403 error.

The quota limit is 1 millon queries per day, I have only used about 1%.
There are approximately 1200 videos already on the channel that were uploaded using the same app, now all of a sudden in the last few days I am getting this error. I've tried uploading videos to another channel and had no problems, so it looks as though the issue is specific to this one channel. Seems as though it's being throttled, but I don't know why?

I have not contravened any terms of service, the videos are original, the account is in good standing and I'm within the quota limit.

If there are any other limits, why does Google not document it in the api refrence? That way we can design our apps according to policy.

It makes it impossible to build an app if you follow spec and then Google have a different set of rules on the backend and you are left guessing what you are and aren't allowed to do.

Using this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples
{
  /// <summary>
  /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: upload a video.
  /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
  /// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
  /// </summary>
  internal class UploadVideo
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("YouTube Data API: Upload Video");
      Console.WriteLine("==============================");

      try
      {
        new UploadVideo().Run().Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ex)
      {
        foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
      UserCredential credential;
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
            // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
        );
      }

      var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
      });

      var video = new Video();
      video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
      video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
      video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
      video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
      video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22"; // See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list
      video.Status = new VideoStatus();
      video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
      var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
      {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
      }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
      switch (progress.Status)
      {
        case UploadStatus.Uploading:
          Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent);
          break;

        case UploadStatus.Failed:
          Console.WriteLine("An error prevented the upload from completing.\n{0}", progress.Exception);
          break;
      }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've started getting the same thing. I've e-mailed support and am awaiting a reply.

Comment: Seems like quite a few people are having this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498808/youtube-data-api-intermittently-throw-access-forbidden    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462748/unable-to-upload-videos-to-youtube-using-java-api-oauth2-receiving-403-access?noredirect=1&lq=1   Please let us know if you hear back from support. Thanks

Comment: I got half an answer from support: “Currently, our engineers are aware of the problem and is still working hard to resolve it.

At the moment, I'm unable to provide a specific timeline for a solution, however once our engineers have applied the fix, it will be automatically implemented in our systems.”