# Application Youtube API limit per day video insert 403 forbidden

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I try to make upload script on youtube channel by this sample code https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

But after 50 video upload script get 403 error

Uploading file...

An HTTP error 403 occurred:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.common",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."
 }
}
```

What happens? My channel quota is about 300000 units!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post links to a code, instead bring the code to here. Remember that links can be changed or deleted and/or have its content modified.

Comment: From the [YouTube Data API - Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors) it is an error about authorization, So make sure that you follow the guides [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) on how to Implement OAuth 2.0 Authorization. Also, take note that service account is not supported in the YouTube API. You can refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/moving_to_oauth#service_accounts) about that.

Comment: If this is not the case of your problem, then check these questions [youtube data api intermittently throw access forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42498808/youtube-data-api-intermittently-throw-access-forbidden) and [Unable to upload videos to youtube using java API (oAuth2). Receiving 403 Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462748/unable-to-upload-videos-to-youtube-using-java-api-oauth2-receiving-403-access) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Auth correct. Code correct too. 50 videos uploaded without problem.

100 video per day is new Google limitation. 
Details here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35919708